# webapp2 autoconversion of request params / handler arguments?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, webapp2

I have the following route and accompanying handler:

```
Route(r'/book/<id:\d+>', handler='handlers.BookHandler') 

def show(self, id): 
        logging.info('in show book handler... %s', id) 
        book = Book.get_by_id(long(id)) 
        self.render_response('book/show.html', book=book)
```

To retrieve the book from the datastore I have to convert the id 
request param to long explicitly.

I'm wondering if webapp2 support something to do autoconversion? 
What I mean is that the id received in the show method is already a 
long.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They will always be strings. Even if regex allow only numbers. webapp2 does not support any autoconversions.